# How can i turn my tableview upside down so new added cells appear at the top and not the button?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have an issue which i hope anyone can help me with. 
I am trying to create my tableview in a way so new data will be added in the top of the tableview instead of the bottom. If you look at the picture below, i typed a in first and d last but i would love to have them in the opposite direction so they would appear d, c, b, a and if i added e, it would appear at the top.

I have already tried working with

```
tableViewOutlet.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -(CGFloat)(Double.pi))

and

cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi));
```

Just to turn my tableview and cells upside down, and it worked fine! the only issue is that my tableview will now start at the bottom of the screen and when the page fills up i would have to scroll up and not down.

[Screenshot of my situation (here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBlHR.png)

I hope someone out there can give me a hand, and help me out!

Best regards Kristofer

Comment: you can add your new object at 0 index every time.

Comment: If it's just the order of your cells that is your concern, a common practice is to assign an `NSDate` timestamp to each entity in your core-data (or as SH_Khan points out, an incremental ID), and sort based on it. If it's UI that's the issue, it's a broad topic with multiple possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to sort the array descending to add integer value to you model array and sort it descending

```
struct mainItem {

  var id: Int
  var userNumber: String
  var address:String


init(id: Int, userNumber: String, address: String )
{


    self.id = id
    self.userNumber = userNumber
    self.address = address


}
}


var arrRet = [mainItem]()


    arrRet = arrRet.sorted(by: {


        var m1 = Int($0.id)

        var m2 = Int($1.id)


        return m1! > m2!


    })
```

Comment: Hi Khan

my app uses coreData so the thing i sort is an entitie of a car where i have the values, date, price, liter, and km. But yea i could try to add an ID in form of int and see if i can sort that. Going to try, thanks!

Comment: That assumes you want the data in a sorted (either forward or reverse) order and just not the opposite of how it was entered.  For example if this was entered A,G,E,D that doesn't mean anything needs to be sorted just it should be in the table as D,E,G,A.

Comment: the added item will have a higher id so sorting descending will bring it at top of cell

Comment: Good point.  My bad for some reason I completely skipped over the adding of an ID.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you can't change how the data is provided (i.e. sort it) then you can change the order of how you access it.

So change this:

```
let data = dataArray[indexPath.row]
```

to this:

```
let data = dataArray[dataArray.count - indexPath.row + 1]
```

Doing this you are just accessing the data array the other way around.

So I have a test dataArray of ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"] and using my method it calculates like this:

```
indexPath.row = 0 --- (5 - 0 - 1) = 4
indexPath.row = 1 --- (5 - 1 - 1) = 3
indexPath.row = 2 --- (5 - 2 - 1) = 2
indexPath.row = 3 --- (5 - 3 - 1) = 1
indexPath.row = 4 --- (5 - 4 - 1) = 0
```

So you have reversed the order in which you access the array.

(Don't mess about with the transform as that will just be a world of hurt)

Comment: Nope the maths is correct and I have an example running in Xcode.  Brackets will make no difference as `dataArray.count - indexPath.row - 1` is the same as `dataArray.count - (indexPath.row - 1)` which is the same as `(dataArray.count - indexPath.row) - 1`.  I will update the question with the example data I am using. (There was a comment about the math being incorrect but it's gone now)

Comment: indexPath.row is not a value for me because i use core data. when i call indexPath.row i get 

<Bilen: 0x6000000998c0> (entity: Bilen; id: 0xd000000000a40000 <x-coredata://FA8BB10D-7A9E-4FEA-948A-ECA6FDCBAD44/Bilen/p41> ; data: {
    dato = c;
    id = 0;
    kilometer = 3;
    liter = 3;
    pris = 3;

Comment: I don't quite understand then.  That line I said to change which uses indexPath.row came directly from the image you linked to as an example.

Comment: It's because my array is an entity of a car and the car has different kind of attributes fx id, kilometers driven and so on.... there for when i use indexPath.row it just shows me all my attributes like in my comment above... Your method is functional tho, i just have to find out how i can get the indexPath.row in numbers! :)

Comment: It shouldn't matter what your array contains as you are only concerned with the objects position in that array (i.e. you want to first item in the array at the bottom of the table and the last item at the top).  Still if you have managed to get it working that's good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **reversed()** method of Swift arrays.

When user enter the string, you will append that to dataArray:-

```
var dataArray: [String] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
dataArray.append("e")
```

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath:-

```
let data = dataArray.reversed()[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel!.text = data
```